# How should I store a log for my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, database

I have a plugin that sends data to a server as part of a `transition_post_status` action. The server sends a response each time. I want to keep a log of these responses (permanently) that I can display in a table to the user somewhere, like so:

```
Date | Response
------------------
1/1  | OK
1/2  | Status code 2
```

What's the best way to do this? Should I create a new database table, or is there a more convenient way?

Some background: I've tried using the [WP_Logging() class](http://pippinsplugins.com/wp-logging/), but it doesn't seem to work correctly when called through an action.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear exactly what you are doing. For example, I am not sure what the data is that you are saving or where/when it needs to be displayed, but it sounds like you need:

1. [The Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)
2. [Or the Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

However, if your data is very complicated you might want a dedicated table. Without more information, that is the best I've got.

Comment: Edited my post. I think the transients api won't work because I need to retain the data permanently, and there will possibly be too much data(?) to store as an option

Comment: The options table "value" column is `longtext`, which is enormous, but again, without the specifics of your project I can't tell you much else.

Comment: ♦ so is it ok just to dump say an array of arrays into a single option value? i.e. `array(array($date, $msg, $post_id), array()…etc)`?

Comment: @Jack : Yes, the string will be serialized. If you use Core functions to insert and retrieve the data the serialization will be transparent.

Comment: The thing is, that seems to mean that each time I want to add a new log item, I have to retrieve the entire log array, append to it, and then put it back. Isn't that going to be horribly inefficient?

Comment: Yes, it could be inefficient, but you don't have to use a single option, and again, the best way to do this depends on the details, and you haven't really provided many.

Answer (score 0):

How I've done it in the end is as follows:

Because it's triggered on `post_status_transition`, each log can be effectively linked to a particular post. Therefore, I can use add/update_post_meta to store the response and timestamp as meta fields for that post.

To retrieve all logs, I can simply do:

```
$logs = array();
        $query_args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'myresponsetimestamp',
            'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                $logs[] = array(
                    'postid' =>$post_id,
                    'time' => get_post_meta( $post_id, 'myresponsetimestamp', true ),
                    'response' =>get_post_meta( $post_id, 'myresponse', true )
                );
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```